# Qt Visual Studio 2015 Add-in compilation problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, add-in

I use Qt Add-in in my project. But i dont understand , what i do uncorrect.

My .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui network
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MMworker
DESTDIR = ../Debug
CONFIG += debug
LIBS += -L"../../../../boost_1_70_0/stage/lib"
DEPENDPATH += .
MOC_DIR += .
OBJECTS_DIR += debug
UI_DIR += .
RCC_DIR += .
```

Get a lot of errors. For example

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QHostAddress::QHostAddress(void)" (__imp_??0QHostAddress@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function...
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall QHostAddress::setAddress(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setAddress@QHostAddress@@QAE_NABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function ...
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall TcpServer::connectToServer(class QHostAddress,int)" (?connectToServer@TcpServer@@QAEXVQHostAddress@@H@Z) referenced in function...
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall MainTimer::timeAfterMomentExceeds(__int64,__int64)" (?timeAfterMomentExceeds@MainTimer@@QAE_N_J0@Z) referenced in function ...
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: __int64 __thiscall MainTimer::getMilliseconds(void)" (?getMilliseconds@MainTimer@@AAE_JXZ) referenced in function "public: __int64 __thiscall MainTimer::time_ms(void)" (?time_ms@MainTimer@@QAE_JXZ)...
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Channel::readData(class QString &)" (?readData@Channel@@QAEXAAVQString@@@Z) referenced in function ...
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall SimpleDevice::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@SimpleDevice@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)...
```

P.S.: Also I look in [qt simple tcp communication with ui projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277835/qt-simple-tcp-communication-with-ui-projects?rq=1) . I dont understand how I can "You need to enable modules you're using in Qt Project Settings".

UPD1: compile was sucsess, but build still falling.

Comment: I've had some trouble with the add-in as well; I even couldn't find out when someone else had it, but let's try anyway. I assume you haven't managed to run any project yet. 1) check if you've installed QtCreator properly - even though you won't be opening the app, it's necessary for VS to work - I believe. 2) run Path/To/Qt/MaintenanceTool.exe and see if the necessary modules are installed. A standard WidgetsApplication requires the `core`, `widget` and `gui` modules. Yours contains already `network`, so you should make sure it's included as well.

Comment: Next to that; I never edit my VS generated `.pro` file, simply, because it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm always in trouble if I need a header from a new module that wasn't included in the project settings, so make sure you've included everything at the start. In meanwhile I should find out how to add libraries after the project has been set.

Comment: How can I check in MaintenanceTool.exe availability of modules? I see only different variants of compilers...

Comment: If I open the Maintenance tool (it asked me to do an update first) I click "add/remove compenents", then I get to see all Qt versions. I for example have Qt 5.14.1. I can then expand the version of which I have my modules and see "Android, MSVC...", but if I look a little further, I also can see "Qt Charts", "Qt Data Visualization". These are modules that are optional. One of them is named "Qt Network Authorization", so I think you need that one (I'm not sure, because I always have a hard time finding the module name). Of course, you can use the latest version 5.15.0 instead of 5.14.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in inlcude additional dependensies(removed) and included dirs(added)